# CRA - how to proxy all requests but a specific one?

Tags: webpack-dev-server, create-react-app, http-proxy-middleware

`create-react-app` [docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuring-the-proxy-manually) says you can configure your proxy objects manually. I'm following the `http-proxy-middleware` [docs on matching](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#context-matching)
to exclude a specific route but haven't got it to work.

Basically I'm serving my app from the `/app` route instead of root. So I want the following to happen:

1. `/app/api` proxies to `http://localhost:3001`, my backend service
2. All requests **that does NOT start with `/app`** proxy to `http://cloud.my-app.com`

This is what I've tried so far with no luck:

```
  "homepage": "https://cloud.my-app.com/app",
  "proxy": {
    "/app/api": {                            // Works
      "target": "http://localhost:3001"
    },
    "!/app/*": {                             // Does not work
      "target": "https://cloud.my-app.com",
      "secure": false
    }
  },
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below as your proxy:

```
  "proxy": {
    "/app/api":{
      "target":"http://localhost:3001",    
   },
    "/.*/":{
      "target":"https://cloud.my-app.com",
      "secure":"false",
      "changeOrigin": true
   }
  }
```